# Check if inputted key and value exists within a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, crud

I was tasked to create a CRUD program using Python dictionaries. I need to write code to check if the inputted key and value already exists in the dictionary, so here is the code of dictionary plus the input that prompt the user to search for ID:

```
products = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Light bulb', 'price': 100, 'stock': 16},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Measuring tape', 'price': 200, 'stock': 34},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Fan', 'price': 120, 'stock': 79},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'Flat shoes', 'price': 260, 'stock': 47},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'Swiss Army knife', 'price': 80, 'stock': 12},
    {'id': 6, 'name': 'Guitar', 'price': 193, 'stock': 25},
    {'id': 7, 'name': 'Marble', 'price': 30, 'stock': 45},
    {'id': 8, 'name': 'Stapler', 'price': 220, 'stock': 78},
    {'id': 9, 'name': 'Wrench and hammer', 'price': 65, 'stock': 12}
]

id_search = int(input("Enter ID product you want to search: ")
```

I wanted to make the if-else statement to see if the ID exists in the products dictionary, otherwise display the message that the ID is not found. I tried the following

```
if id_search in products:
     print("Product ID found")
else:
     print("Product ID not found")
```

But the result is always "Product ID not found".

Comment: because id is not the key of your dictionary. You have a list of dictionaries. Make a dict with id as key instead and the rest as values for example: `products = {d["id"]:d for d in products}`

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of `dict`s not just a `dict`. You have to search through list of `dict`s:

```py
found = False
for product in products:
    if product.get("id") == id_search:
        found = True
        break

print(found)
```

Note that if your `dict`s are sorted, you probably can use binary search.

Comment: Or as a oneliner: `found = any([product.get('id') == id_search for product in products])`. Probably a bit slower though.

Comment: As an alternative to doing some sort of custom search, I would be very tempted to turn `products` into a dictionary. `products = {p["id"] : p for p in products}`. then `products.values()` could always be used to revert it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len([[*my_dict.values()][0] for my_dict in products if [*my_dict.values()][0] == id_search]) > 0:
  print("Product ID found")
else: 
  print("Product ID not found")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?